# On refreshing the page, applied CSS style to the static value disappears. How can we prevent this?

Tags: javascript, css

I am displaying a static value and a button using pure javascript and CSS.
    I have written the code in such a way that, on click of the button, the 
    color of the static value changes to red. The issue over here is,
    When I refresh the page, red color of the static value disappears. 
    I want the static value to be red even after I refresh the page.
    Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

```js
function fn1() {
  var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
  var data = 0;
  data = v1[0].innerHTML;
  if (data >= 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  } else if (data < 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "-$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    v1[0].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <body>
    value :
    <h2 class="class1"> -100</h2><br><br>
    <!-- on click of button call function -->
    <button onclick="fn1()">CLICK</button>
    <!--<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)" onclick="fn1()">Refresh Page</a>          -->
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: current o/p: on click of button,static value is -$100.00 in red, but, on 
    page refresh o/p is -100 in black.
    Expected o/p: after page refresh also, o/p should be -$100.00 in red.

Comment: Use session/local storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the cookie, localStorage or sessionStorage to fix this issue. For now I'm using localStorage to store the latest CSS style color. The updated code is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        value : <h2 class="class1"> -100</h2><br><br>
        <!-- on click of button call function -->
        <button onclick="fn1()">CLICK</button>
        <!--<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)" onclick="fn1()">Refresh Page</a>          -->
    </body>

    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
        function fn1() {


            var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
            var data = 0;
            data = v1[0].innerHTML;
            if (data >= 0) {

                v1[0].innerHTML = "$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

            } else if (data < 0) {

                v1[0].innerHTML = "-$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                //setting color in local storage
                window.localStorage.setItem('color','red');
                v1[0].style.color = "red";

            }
        }
        //getting color from local storage
        v1[0].style.color = window.localStorage.getItem('color');

    </script>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to reset the color from red to black according to your use else once you set the color to red it will always show it as red.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    color = localStorage.getItem("color")
    if(color){
        document.getElementById("class1").style.color = color;
    }
function fn1() {
  var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
  var data = 0;
  data = v1[0].innerHTML;
  if (data >= 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  } else if (data < 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "-$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    v1[0].style.color = "red";
    cc = window.localStorage.setItem("color", "red")
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <body>
    value :
    <h2 class="class1" id="class1"> -100</h2><br><br>
    <!-- on click of button call function -->
    <button onclick="fn1()">CLICK</button>
    <!--<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)" onclick="fn1()">Refresh Page</a>          -->
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with `localStorage`:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function fn1() {
  var v1 = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
  var data = 0;
  data = v1[0].innerHTML;
  if (data >= 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  } else if (data < 0) {
    v1[0].innerHTML = "-$" + (Math.round(Math.abs(data) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    v1[0].style.color = "red";
    setLocalStorageItem()
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fn1()
})

setColorOnLoad()

function setColorOnLoad() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('static') === true) {
    fn1()
  }
}

function setLocalStorageItem() {
  localStorage.setItem('static', true)
}
```

HTML:

```
value :
<h2 class="class1"> -100</h2><br><br>
<!-- on click of button call function -->
<button id="btn1">CLICK</button>
<!--<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)" onclick="fn1()">Refresh Page</a>          -->
```

It's not a good practice to use the `onclick` in HTML - rather add an ID and an `eventListener` in JS.

I also suggest that you **set a name in the localStorage according to the state of your app - and not the attribute**. Most of the time you don't want it to be "red", but show that it has a special state (like "static"). If you set localStorage to "color: red", and you want to change it in the future (like for "green"), then you'll have two things to look for. If you set the localStorage item like "static: true", **then it doesn't matter if it's for example green, red, underlined, or hidden - you just change formatting in one place in your code**.